# Polygon projection fail with osmnx

Tags: python, coordinate-system, osmnx

I download a graph and plotted an accessability polygon on the projected graph according to [tutorial](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb)

```
G = ox.project_graph(G) #
```

Then I wanted to project my accessibilty polygon `g1` back to `'epsg:3857'` with this code

```
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import transform

project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(
    pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj('epsg:3857')) # destination coordinate system
g2 = transform(project.transform, g1)  # apply projection
```

But when I print g2 there emerges an error despite the fact that g1 can be plotted and gives no errors

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

~\Anaconda3\envs\dsenv\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py in _repr_svg_(self)
    392             if xmin == xmax and ymin == ymax:
    393                 # This is a point; buffer using an arbitrary size
--> 394                 xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = self.buffer(1).bounds
    395             else:
    396                 # Expand bounds by a fraction of the data ranges

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)

<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x18625802700>
```

Is this a correct way to convert a polygon? Or have I mistaken the projection type?

**UPD**
If I exchange the sequence of projections `pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326')`, `pyproj.Proj('epsg:3857')` to `pyproj.Proj('epsg:3857')`, `pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326')`
then I get the polygon but its centroid contains wrong cordinates. So maybe the correct question is, which projection is used for ox.project_graph?

Comment: I solved the problem, I should have converted my polygons to pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326') from corresponding UTM zone projection

Comment: Hi James Flash. Will be helpful for other users if you can answer your own question. Since it seems to be answered in a comment, we are voting to close it as a no longer reproducible question.